# NetSuite: Duplicating value from custom transaction col field to class (line) field

Tags: transactions, netsuite

We are looking to duplicate the value from a custom transaction column field to the class field. The field we are looking to duplicate is populated by a program outside NS. We need to carry the value over on the transaction line for reporting purposes. We have attempted using Suite Scripts but are unable to select the custom field as the value for class. We have not been able to access the "class" field when attempting "Mass Update." We attempted to import csv file but are unable to update to map transaction lines which has lead to duplicating lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all the values you want available to set `Class` to are already setup in the Classes list (Add/update at: Setup->Company->Classes)

There are some complications in automating the copying of these if the values of the custom field is not a direct type *match* to the `Class` field.  These can be handled by someone familiar with SuiteScript.

Alternatively, if you have access to the *program outside NS*, you could simply update it to set the `Class` directly, when it interacts with the transaction line. (You'll still need to have added the appropriate values to the Classes list, as above.)